# group and display object array in .cmp

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, aura

2 week salesforce noob in need..... I take an Object array in, as my attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="sectionStandard" type="Object[]"/>
```

I wish to build a nested display loop that will group according to distinct values in category field.

```
sectionStandard.category
```

Then per category display the following where the key is the distinct category.

```
                 <aura:iteration var="sectionStandard" items="{!v.sectionStandardsData}">
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {!v.sectionStandard.Audit_Standard__r.Standard_Code__c}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {!v.sectionStandard.Audit_Standard__r.Standard_Name__c}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {!v.sectionStandard.Audit_Standard__r.Standard_Website_URL__c}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                 </aura:iteration>
```

Im thinking this is possible with a javascript map with Key value as category...
Just having some difficulty laying this out :) any tips welcome. Will post solution if I figure it out soon.